# Windows10 volume balance resets

Tags: windows-10, audio

In windows 10 audio mixer:

- Set balance to a new level.
- Change master volume to 0%
- Turn up master volume.
- Balance resets back to 50%

I can't believe they can't get this right in 2021, they add ton of useless UI just to hide the option, but finally after you find it it just wouldn't work. Customer support asked me to reinstall the OS for this..